# 1TB or 2TB on a MacBook Pro 15 Inch

Tags: mac, macbook-pro

I purchased a 15 inch Unibody Macbook Pro today. I was wondering if I can do a harddrive upgrade up to 1TB or 2TB on it. I need that space because I want to store all my junk on it.

What is the maximum capacity I can upgrade the hard drive to? If so, where can I find those hard drives?

Comment: You have lots of junk...

Answer (score 1):

You can put whatever HD you like if they exists as SATA2 2.5''. To change it you can proceed by hand by following the instructions provided on booklet..

In any case it's a simple operation that doesn't involve any complex step, hard-disks of macbooks are just normal SATA2 hard-disks so it's just as upgrading a normal pc..

Answer (score 1):

The good news is that you can now get 1TB laptop hard drives, the bad news is that I have only seen them in 5400RPM drives which are slower when compared to 7200RPM Drives.

[See here](http://www.wdc.com/en/products/Products.asp?DriveID=685) for more information.

Please note however, it is not easy on a Macbook to change the hard drive and you will need to reload OSX from scratch.

[Here is a good video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lcMtKfDIKHY) that should be able to help you if you have not done this before.

Comment: no, you won't have to reload OSx - You can just copy the existing partition using disk utility if you have a spare external case

Answer (score 0):

You can choose any 2.5 inch hard drive you would like, however, there are size restrictions.  I believe the 15 inch macbook pro's though can only use 9.5mm height drives and not the bigger 12.5mm drives.  So even though there are 1 tb 2.5 inch drives out there, they are all 12.5mm height and will not fit the macbook pro.

The largest 2.5inch 5400rpm 9.5mm height drive currently on the market is 750gb.

http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=100007605+600030599&QksAutoSuggestion=&ShowDeactivatedMark=False&Configurator=&IsNodeId=1&Subcategory=380&description=&Ntk=&CFG=&SpeTabStoreType=&srchInDesc=

The largest 2.5inch 7200rpm 9.5mm height drive currently on the market is 640gb.

http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822152237

Answer (score 0):

The 17inch models will allow the larger laptop drives (12.5mm) but they only extend to 1tb these days.  You could alway perform a Time machine backup and restore or just take a snapshot of the drive with Super Duper or any cloning program to avoid having to reinstall everything.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed a 12.5mm 1 tb Toshiba drive in my macbook pro 15" no problem.

The added height for the battery alongside it makes it possible.

Comment: This is not a discussion board. Please edit your answer so it's a proper reply to the original question and doesn't attack other posters.

Comment: Why are you so bitter ? As @DanielBeck mentions - attacking others is of little use.

Answer (score -2):

Go for 2TB, I use hitachi drives. [Try here](http://www.ebuyer.com/search?page=1&q=2tb&subcat=1090)

Comment: Does this work for a 2010 15 inch macbook pro?

Comment: @Vin No, those will not work. Those are 3.5inch destktop size drives. There are no 2tb 2.5 inch drives ... yet.